# First Windows driver development exercise: dev/random or dev/null?

Tags: windows, windows-10, driver

What follows is really a learning exercise and not necessarily a search for a production solution.  I've recently done a bunch of reading about Windows driver development and am looking for a first good exercise in practical application before potentially proceeding toward a future win10 mobile device family project.

Just to get my feet wet with win10 driver development, I was thinking it would be interesting to develop (and then publish) a filesystem driver project that implemented a dumb Windows equivalent of /dev/null or /dev/random - really, any virtual device that I can read a stream of data from.

I haven't done much Windows development in the past, but after reading through a couple books on Safari I've landed on MS's [driver samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples) GitHub page, which seems like a good start, but doesn't seem to provide a clear way forward from what I've read so far.

Right now I'm still casting about with web searches and would sure appreciate some guidance in how to proceed toward this goal (references, reading materials, etc) I'll be happy to publish whatever silly project(s) I wind up generating for others to learn from in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to start Windows driver development is with [toaster sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/toaster/toastDrv) . It will provide you basic workable understanding of Windows driver development. You will be able to understand basics for writing bus driver, function driver and filter drivers(upper, lower) in Windows.